# Find out number of words in file that do not match any word in the String array

Tags: java, arrays, regex, string

I am trying to create a program that reads data from a file. I want each time to check if the next word from the file matches with a specific word from a specific String array.

Each time the words don't match, I want to keep track of the times as (wrong++) and print the number of times the words from the file didn't match at least one word from the String Array.

Here is my program:

```
public class main_class {

    public static int num_wrong;
    public static java.io.File file = new java.io.File("text.txt");
    public static String[] valid_letters = new String[130];
    public static boolean wrong = true;
    public static String[] sample = new String[190];

    public static void text_file() throws Exception {
        // Create Scanner to read file

        Scanner input = new Scanner(file);

        String[] valid_letters = { "I", " have ", " got ", "a", "date", "at",
                "quarter", "to", "eight", "8", "7:45", "I’ll", "see", "you",
                "the", "gate", ",", "so", "don’t", "be", "late", "We",
                "surely", "shall", "sun", "shine", "soon", "would", "like",
                "sit", "here", "cannot", "hear", "because", "of", "wood",
                "band", "played", "its", "songs", "banned", "glamorous",
                "night", "sketched", "a", "drone", "flying", "freaked", "out",
                "when", "saw", "squirrel", "swimming", "man", "had", "cat",
                " that", "was", "eating", "bug", "After", "dog", "got", "wet",
                "Ed", "buy", "new", "pet", "My", "mom", "always", "tells",
                "me", "beautiful", "eyes", "first", "went", "school", "wanted",
        "die" };

        while (input.hasNext()) {
            String[] sample = input.next().split("\t");

            for (int i = 0; i < valid_letters.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++) {
                    if (sample[j] == valid_letters[i]) {
                        boolean wrong = false;
                        System.out.print("break");
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (wrong = true) {
                num_wrong++;
            }
        }

        // print out the results from the search
        System.out
        .print(" The number of wrong words in the first 13 sentences are "
                + num_wrong);
        // Close the file
        input.close();
    }
}
```

The text file for example contains:

```
I want to go to school little monkey
```

And the program should return the number of mistakes are **`2`**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Code:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class main_class {

    public static int num_wrong = 0;
    public static java.io.File file = new java.io.File("text.txt");
    public static String[] valid_letters = new String[130];
    public static boolean wrong = true;
    public static String[] sample = new String[190];

    public static void main (String [] args) {
        try {
            text_file();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void text_file() throws Exception {
        // Create Scanner to read file    
        Scanner input = new Scanner(file);

        String [] valid_letters = { "I", " have ", " got ", "a", "date", "at",
                "quarter", "to", "eight", "8", "7:45", "I’ll", "see", "you",
                "the", "gate", ",", "so", "don’t", "be", "late", "We",
                "surely", "shall", "sun", "shine", "soon", "would", "like",
                "sit", "here", "cannot", "hear", "because", "of", "wood",
                "band", "played", "its", "songs", "banned", "glamorous",
                "night", "sketched", "a", "drone", "flying", "freaked", "out",
                "when", "saw", "squirrel", "swimming", "man", "had", "cat",
                " that", "was", "eating", "bug", "After", "dog", "got", "wet",
                "Ed", "buy", "new", "pet", "My", "mom", "always", "tells",
                "me", "beautiful", "eyes", "first", "went", "school", "wanted",
                "die" };

        while (input.hasNext()) {
            // NOTE: split using space, i.e. " "
            String[] sample = input.next().split(" ");

            // NOTE: j < sample.length
            for (int j = 0; j < sample.length; j++) 
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < valid_letters.length; i++) 
                {
                    // NOTE: string comparison is using equals
                    if (sample[j].equals(valid_letters[i])) {

                        // NOTE: You want to update the variable wrong.
                        // And not create a local variable 'wrong' here!
                        wrong = false;
                        System.out.printf("%-12s is inside!%n",
                                "'" + valid_letters[i] + "'");
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (wrong) {
                    num_wrong++;
                }
                // Reset wrong
                wrong = true;
            }
        }

        // Print out the results from the search
        System.out.println("The number of wrong words in the first 13 sentences are "
                + num_wrong);
        // Close the file
        input.close();
    }
}
```

**Input** (Stored in "text.txt"):

```
I want to go to school little monkey
```

**Output:**

```
'I'          is inside!
'to'         is inside!
'to'         is inside!
'school'     is inside!
The number of wrong words in the first 13 sentences are 4
//'go', 'want', 'little' and 'monkey' are not inside the String array
```

**Note:**

- `Value` comparison of String is using `equals`, not `==` ( used for `Reference` comparision)
- `boolean wrong = false;` creates a local variable
- Your for loop should be using `j < sample.length`
- The string should be split using `" "` (space), and not `"\t"` (tab)

Comment: `+l ` But, you forgot the main change.. `\t` doesnt work.. it should be `(space)` or `\\s`

Comment: @karthikmanchala Right, changed quite a few places, forgot about that! Thanks!!

Comment: you really helped me my friend thank you!Congrats!Both of you actually

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do this quickly you could make a ternary tree or hash dynamically
if you expect the word list to change.

If the word list doesn't change, you can avoid having to split the words and   make a ternary tree into a complete regex trie. Then do a find all to get all the words not in the list.

This regex trie is a *very fast* way to do it.

You can auto-generate a regex from a list of words using this trial application 
*regexformat.com*.
Set it for case insensitive and whitespace word boundary.

Just tweak the output group into a  negative lookahead, as in below.

```
 # "(?i)(?<!\\S)(?!(?:,|7:45|8|a(?:fter|lways|t)?|b(?:an(?:d|ned)|e(?:autiful|cause)?|u(?:g|y))|ca(?:nnot|t)|d(?:ate|ie|o(?:g|n’t)|rone)|e(?:ating|d|ight|yes)|f(?:irst|lying|reaked)|g(?:ate|lamorous|ot)|h(?:a(?:d|ve)|e(?:ar|re))|i(?:ts|’ll)?|l(?:ate|ike)|m(?:an|e|om|y)|n(?:ew|ight)|o(?:f|ut)|p(?:et|layed)|quarter|s(?:aw|chool|ee|h(?:all|ine)|it|ketched|o(?:ngs|on)?|quirrel|u(?:n|rely)|wimming)|t(?:ells|h(?:at|e)|o)|w(?:a(?:nted|s)|e(?:nt|t)?|hen|o(?:od|uld))|you)(?!\\S))\\S+(?!\\S)"

 (?i)
 (?<! \S )
 (?!
      (?:
           ,
        |  7:45
        |  8
        |  a
           (?: fter | lways | t )?
        |  b
           (?:
                an
                (?: d | ned )
             |  e
                (?: autiful | cause )?
             |  u
                (?: g | y )
           )
        |  ca
           (?: nnot | t )
        |  d
           (?:
                ate
             |  ie
             |  o
                (?: g | n’t )
             |  rone
           )
        |  e
           (?: ating | d | ight | yes )
        |  f
           (?: irst | lying | reaked )
        |  g
           (?: ate | lamorous | ot )
        |  h
           (?:
                a
                (?: d | ve )
             |  e
                (?: ar | re )
           )
        |  i
           (?: ts | ’ll )?
        |  l
           (?: ate | ike )
        |  m
           (?: an | e | om | y )
        |  n
           (?: ew | ight )
        |  o
           (?: f | ut )
        |  p
           (?: et | layed )
        |  quarter
        |  s
           (?:
                aw
             |  chool
             |  ee
             |  h
                (?: all | ine )
             |  it
             |  ketched
             |  o
                (?: ngs | on )?
             |  quirrel
             |  u
                (?: n | rely )
             |  wimming
           )
        |  t
           (?:
                ells
             |  h
                (?: at | e )
             |  o
           )
        |  w
           (?:
                a
                (?: nted | s )
             |  e
                (?: nt | t )?
             |  hen
             |  o
                (?: od | uld )
           )
        |  you
      )
      (?! \S )
 )
 \S+ 
 (?! \S )
```

Comment: I haven't seen this way before so i can't understand

Comment: @ChristosAntoniou - Well, you can try it out and see what happens. I don't know Java lang too well, buy I know Java regex. Posted a compressed (quoted) string there. Put it in a _find all_ type regex function and see what happens. The number of elements are the number of mistakes you're looking for.

Comment: Yeah, and basically the tool generates a ternary tree internally, then composes a full blown regex _trie_ from that. Full blown meaning every level is factored. In fact the string size of the regex is actually less than the string size of the list of words.

Comment: @ChristosAntoniou - Just to note that the way you are doing this is to loop through a split list of input, in each pass you are looping over the entire arrayed list of words for no matches. This can be optimized. However, with the ternary tree made into a full regex trie, this cuts down the search time for each input word to the level of a hash lookup. This is an industrial strength way to do it, easily accommodating a 180,000 word dictionary. I know its just an exercise though. Good Luck !!

Comment: @sln +1 for using a trie! :)

Answer (score 0):

I can see two mistakes.

```
if(wrong = true)
```

I think you meant

```
if(wrong == true)
```

also, this loop :

```
for (int j= 0 ; j < 1 ; j ++ )
```

Will only do it for j = 0, because it will stop right after. I think you meant

```
for (int j= 0 ; j < sample[i].length ; j ++ )
```

Comment: Yes i know, but i'm just showing what i think he wanted to say, and what was the error.

Comment: i did it but it couldn't even compile..it showed a bound array erro

Answer (score 0):

use collection like List, so that instead of iterating over array of string every time, you can simply do list.contains("word")

```
List<String> validWords = new ArrayList<String>
validWords.add("I");
validWords.add("More words ..");

int wrongCount = 0;

while (input.hasNext())
{
    String [] sample = input.next().split("\t");    

    for ( int i = 0 ; i < sample.length ; i++)
    {
        if (!validWords.contains(sample[i]))
        {
            wrongCount ++ ;
        }
    }
}

System.out.print(" The number of wrong words" + wrongCount ) ;
// .....
```

**note:** Re-declaring global variable at method level is wrong. valid_letters, sample. you can initialize them while declaring them in main method, and you don't have to specify a static array size.

second, your code breaks from the loop once the first matching word found, this way you avoid to check the remaining words, is this what you desired to do ? if so you can edit my code accordingly.